# How to add parent node in XML using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML code

```
<person>
  <name>prane</name>
  <age>19</age>
</person>
<person>
  <name>neeth</name>
  <age>20</age>
</person>
```

Now I want to add parent node using c# the resulting XML should be

```
<persons>
   <person>
      <name>prane</name>
      <age>19</age>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>neeth</name>
      <age>20</age>
   </person>
</persons>
```

How can it be done?

Comment: It would help to see what you currently using to manipulate XML so appropriate recommendations can be made. There are couple existing questions about adding nodes to XML (you can find them by https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+add+node+xml) - see if any of the questions help and possibly let you add more specific details to your post.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation or wiki for the XML library you are using? Or even just googling `[xml library] insert parent`??

Comment: Your first example isn't XML as it has multiple root nodes. So, given this you are really working with strings and not XML. This then becomes plain string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can not be XML,it just looks like XML,because it does have root elements,if the xml you said just a string,you can do like this

```
string xml = @"<person>
  <name>prane</name>
  <age>19</age>
</person>
<person>
  <name>neeth</name>
  <age>20</age>
</person>";
            XElement root = XElement.Parse(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "<persons>", xml, "</persons>"));
```